# How to draw Unicode tick in C?

Tags: c, unicode, command-line, printf, solaris

I'm working on a testing framework which prints to the command-line and instead of 'Pass'/'Fail', I would like to print ticks (check mark) for pass and crosses for fail. I found the symbols at the bottom of [this wingdings character set](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html), and I've seen these exact ones used before in [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) (a javascript unit test framework)

Can I print them from C using a simple `printf`? Examples would be smashing, thanks!

p.s: I'm using *nix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on your platform, and whether the terminal (the program that receives the `printf()` output and renders it as readable text) is Unicode-aware.

If it's running e.g. UTF-8, you can print [the character's](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm) UTF-8 sequence:

```
/* This prints a ✓. */
printf("\xE2\x9C\x93\n");
```

Comment: That's very slick. It works from the shell as well: `printf "\xE2\x9C\x93\n"`